# How to define the directory path of a file on my hard disk

Tags: perl

I am having a problem when I want ro run a program which is my personal folder `/home/student/trap/trap.pl`, although I run this program from my hard disk only by defining the directory.

The problem is that I need to open a file located in my hard disk running this program, e.g.:

```
perl ~/trap/trap.pl -i <path>
```

`<path>` is the directory of my file, which is

```
/media/student/My Book/microsat/TRF_output/concatenated_reads_N10.fasta
```

It does not work. It says that the directory does not exist...

How should I write this?

I have to mention that I've also tried with `../TRF_output/concatenated_reads.fasta` and some other ways, but did not succeed.

Comment: Did you try to give the path in double quotation marks `"` like this: `"/media/student/My Book/microsat/TRF_output/concatenated_reads_N10.fasta"`? Because you have a blank in the path.

Comment: Probably correct @takkat but  I fail to see the relation to Ubunt. This is a coding problem.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is quite simple. This path you give to your program isn't valid. The problem is My Book. Either you quote your path like

```
'/media/student/My Book/microsat/TRF_output/concatenated_reads_N10.fasta'
```

or you escape the space with a backslash

```
/media/student/My\ Book/microsat/TRF_output/concatenated_reads_N10.fasta
```